# R convert dictionary to list

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe

I have a list (or dictionary) like this:

```
df <- list(`digits/trainingDigits/0_0.txt` = c(0, 1, 1, 0), `digits/trainingDigits/0_1.txt` = c(0, 1, 0, 0), `digits/trainingDigits/0_10.txt` = c(0, 0, 1, 0))
```

I would like to convert it to a list like:

```
df <- list(c(0, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Somehow removing the text before the "=". I am quite new to r, I assume it's like a Python dictionary with keys and values. In this case, I would like to have the list of values.

So at the end I would have this:

```
df2 <- list(c(0, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 0))

df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)
t(df2)
```

With this outcome:

[image]

Comment: so do you want a list of lists or a data frame?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new with the R vocabulary. At the end I would like a dataframe like  the screenshot. But I assume I need a list before converting to dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <- list(
  `digits/trainingDigits/0_0.txt` = c(0, 1, 1, 0),
  `digits/trainingDigits/0_1.txt` = c(0, 1, 0, 0),
  `digits/trainingDigits/0_10.txt` = c(0, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

The above is a named list. Let's remove the names:

```
str(unname(dat))
## List of 3
##  $ : num [1:4] 0 1 1 0
##  $ : num [1:4] 0 1 0 0
##  $ : num [1:4] 0 0 1 0
```

Now the above is an unnamed list. We can turn that into a numeric matrix:

```
do.call(rbind, unname(dat))
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    0    1    1    0
## [2,]    0    1    0    0
## [3,]    0    0    1    0
```

Then turn that into a data frame:

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, unname(dat)))
##   V1 V2 V3 V4
## 1  0  1  1  0
## 2  0  1  0  0
## 3  0  0  1  0
```

Comment: It worked I think. Now I need to apply the KNN algorithm, which keeps giving me an error.
Many thanks!

Comment: i forgot to add some context. one sec.